# Date format with UTC

Tags: sql, oracle, date, plsql, oracle10g

I have to select the value 2019-03-25 from a date column of a table but in the following format:

```
2019-03-25T00:00:00.000+02:00
```

Hon can I get it?

Oracle 10g

Thanks!

Comment: The `date` datatype has no milliseconds and no timezone. Do you want to force constant values?

Comment: Also asked on OraFAQ - http://www.orafaq.com/forum/m/681132/#msg_681132

Answer (score 0):

The `date` datatype does not store milliseconds and timezone information, so I undertand your question as how to format a  `date` to the target forma, with fixed values for milliseconds and timezone.

If so, you can use `to_char()` like so:

```
to_char(mycol, 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss".000+2:00"')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `CAST` your `DATE` to a `TIMESTAMP` and then use `FROM_TZ` to set the time zone and then format it to your requirements using `TO_CHAR`:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(
         FROM_TZ( CAST( your_date AS TIMESTAMP ), '+02:00' ),
        'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3TZH:TZM'
       ) AS formatted_date
FROM   your_table;
```

Which, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE your_table ( your_date ) AS
SELECT DATE '2019-03-25' FROM DUAL
```

Outputs:

> ```
> | FORMATTED_DATE                |
> | :---------------------------- |
> | 2019-03-25T00:00:00.000+02:00 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=063c8355f5d15f74580f08a61c8f3a1b)*

Answer (score 0):

We can not store timezone information in db that's why we can simply use below format,

```
select to_char(sysdate,'YYYY-MM-DD')||'T'||to_char(sysdate,'HH24:MI:SS') from dual
```